# Why do crash reports only show up to iOS 8.2?

Tags: app-store-connect

[image: screencap]

There's nothing newer than iOS 8.2 shown on here although newer OSes have been released.

How do I view crash reports of iOS 8.3-iOS 9?

Comment: Is it possible you don't have enough users to have any crashes in the timeframe when those OS were released?

Comment: @bmike Possibly, I've had maybe 15 crashes according to Analytics. It doesn't even show the newer OS'es though